# Android, bottom tab host in fragment, how to?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, tabbar, fragment-tab-host

I would like to ask how to add bottom tab host into fragment?

I tried several tutorials but each from them worked with activity and no fragment.

Many thanks for any step-by-step how to.

Comment: what do you mean by bottom tab host? do you want to show tabs at the bottom of page?

Comment: Hello, Yes I want to add three tabs in the bottom of the page.

Comment: and also do you want to use with viewpager?

Comment: No, I just have the fragment and and i want do display on this fragment tab host at the bottom of the page. Fragment is used for list o items.

Comment: ok whats happen when user click on tabs?

Comment: Is called method for list writeout with different params. List items with daily, month and year stats..

Comment: i think you need bottom instead of tabs and when user press that just reload your list with different adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60792/discussion-between-redrom-and-mmlooloo).